# Convert name to ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python3 program that turns your name into ASCII. Can someone please help? I know you have to use (ch) but I'm struggling to seperate the letters of the name and print it on a different line like the example below.

For example, if you enter your name as John, it'll print:

```
J 74
O 79
H 72
N 110
```

Comment: Use the `ord` builtin. `ord('J')` -> `74`

Comment: Where is your problematic code? [mre] Solving this are 2 lines of code. You need a for loop and a method that gives you the ascii value of the letter.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
>>> name = input('Enter name->')  # take input name
Enter name->JOHN
>>> for char in name:  # iterate over each character
...   print(char, ord(char))  # display output according to your need
... 
J 74
O 79
H 72
N 78
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name=input()
for i in name:
    print(i+" "+str(ord(i)))
```

ord() will do the trick of converting character to corresponding ASCII. So sit back and relax.